# Can a stationary point be a global extremum?

Tags: calculus

My teacher said it can't be, and that is apparently why we have to use a sign chart to find the sign of the 1st derivative on both sides of each critical point instead of just comparing all the y values.

Comment: What is your definition of stationary point? The usual definition is a point where the derivative is zero, in which case the global extrema (of a differentiable function) *must be* stationary points.

Comment: @mephistolotl we're using the definition that a stationary point is the point where the derivative is zero *and* it does not change sign at the point, so for example (0,0) on f(x) = x^3 but not (0,0) on f(x) = x^2

Comment: usually you'd call that a point of inflexion which is also a stationary point

Comment: @Insanit Just for my own education, which country are you studying in and which text are you using? I've never seen that definition.

Comment: @mephistolotl canada but i think we are learning about points of inflection soon so maybe it was just a temporary definition, idk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that's not what your teacher really said (or meant to say).  Of course a stationary point **can be** a global extremum, but it **might not** be, and you can use the signs of the derivative on either side of the stationary point to check whether it is a local extremum.

Comment: if the derivative doesn't change sign at that point can it still be a local extremum (and thus possibly a global extremum)?

Comment: In that case it is an inflexion point with the value of its derivative being 0, which is definitely not considered as a extremum.

Answer (score 0):

Sure how about $f(x) = x^2$ which has a global extremum at $0$ which is also a turning point.

But also consider $f(x) = x^3$ whos turning points aren't global extremum.